# Upload Image to Slack from URL (Not linked)

Tags: google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I'm using Google App Script to send an image to Slack hourly but it's only linking the image which changes regularly at the same URL.

Is it possible to grab an image from a URL and upload to Slack via API so I have the hourly history of the image? Currently if I look at a message from yesterday it's the same image as today since it's only a link.

`

```
function SendToSlack() {
  
      var content = {
      "channel":"updates",
      "text":"Hourly Update",
      "attachments": [
        {
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "title": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Hourly",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "image_url": "https://imageurl",
                    "alt_text": "image"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    };
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://hooks.slack.com/services/###",
      {
        method: "post",
        payload: JSON.stringify(content),
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
      })
  }
```

`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is it possible to send an image hosted elsewhere so I have the hourly history of the image?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I've updated my post for clarity.  I want to take an image from a URL and upload the file to Slack, not the link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to upload an image file to Slack. In this case, I think that Webhook cannot be used. It is required to use "files.upload" of Slack API. [Ref](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) In this case, it is required to use the access token. But, I cannot know whether this is included in your actual expected result. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from Apps Script but you will need a Slack application as Tanaike is suggesting.

This is because you need to use the [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) endpoint to upload an image, and this requires the `files:write` bot or user scope. You could do this easily if you own the Slack server by going to api.slack.com and generating an application for this purpose specifically, authorising it with your domain, and then simply copying the bot token to your application to be passed as part of the `files.upload` request.

If you don't own the server, you will either need someone to provide this for you who can authorise the app manually, or build an oauth authentication loop to retrieve the bot token.

Comment: the part I'm struggling with is where to put the URL of the image I want to upload.  I don't see that on https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

Comment: You can't pass a URL to this method because as you've identified, it doesn't take one. You'll need instead to download the image from the URL as part of your script, and then pass the file data to the `files.upload` method. There's an example of that here, where first the file is downloaded to a stream, and then it is uploaded as referenced https://github.com/hackclub/guardian/blob/1f4ad0d7a8759eb68f77fd9b02a0b162ffe78f62/src/features/reports.ts#L200